# Using LINQ with wrapped arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I'm new to LINQ and I'm doing a simple project to learn the features of the technology.

Currently I've got a static class that wraps an array of object (a kind of simple factory). Let's say it looks like the following:

```
public static class Factory
{
    private static Item[] items = new Item[]
    {
        // items are created here
    };

    // ...
}
```

Now I can add some functions to my Factory that allow me to query the inner array, e.g.

```
    public static Item GetByID(ItemID id)
    {
        var query = 
            from item in items
            where item.ID == id
            select item;

        return query.First();
    }
```

However, this requires me to modify the internals of the Factory class. Is there a way to write such queries from the 'outer world' instead ?

```
public class OtherClass
{
    var result = from it in Factory select ...
}
```

?

Comment: If it's a public property, you can access it. `Factory.WhicheverCollection.Where(item => item.id == whicheverid)` What's the problem?

Comment: I meant using the inner array without exposing it. Something similar to adding an [] operator, which allows a user to use the object as a container.

Comment: You could do that if the class can be iterated on. The way you should do that is to make the class implement `IEnumerable`. From memory, Linq does something odd and can act on anything with a GetIterator or something, but you probably shouldn't trust that.

Comment: Understood - in your opinion which approach is better ? The one with making the inner collection public or the one with implementing IEnumerable ?

Comment: @AlojzyLeszcz: It depends on what you want to allow people outside of your class to *do* with your factory's data. Do you want to allow them to read all of it? To modify it? To replace it?

Comment: A public `get` with a private `set` for your property is definitely the way I'd do it. Interfaces declare intent to a rather large extent. If you want people thinking of a `Factory` as a list, then `IEnumerable` is a good choice. IMO, nothing named `Factory` should ever be a list, because no one would ever expect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to implement `IQueryable<T>` for a non-static class:

```
public class Factory<T> : IQueryable<T>
{
    protected T[] _items = new T[]{};

    public Type ElementType
    {
        // or typeof(T)
        get { return _items.AsQueryable().ElementType; }
    }

    public System.Linq.Expressions.Expression Expression
    {
        get { return _items.AsQueryable().Expression; }
    }

    public IQueryProvider Provider
    {
        get { return _items.AsQueryable().Provider; }
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ( IEnumerator<T> )_items.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _items.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Derive non-generic class to populate array (if desired)

```
public class ItemFactory : Factory<Item>
{
    public ItemFactory()
    {
        // items are created here
    }
}
```

Create static instance

```
public static class Factories
{
    private static ItemFactory _itemFactory = new ItemFactory();
    public static ItemFactory ItemFactory { get { return _itemFactory; } }
}
```

Usage:

```
var specificItem = Factories.ItemFactory
    .Where( item => item.ID == id )
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. Just use linq on the Factory from the 'outer world':

```
public class OtherClass
{
    public Item Get(ItemId id)
    {
       return Factory.Items.SingleOrDefault(i => i.ID == id);
    }
}
```

Of course, to do this, you'd need to change the access modifier of the `items` array to be `public`.

Comment: That's the point - can this be done without exposing the inner collection, but using the wrapping class instead ?

Comment: You would have to add a Get method to your Factory, that was public, that returned you the array `items`, which the 'outer world' could then use linq to operate upon. Realize that this is only semantically different, but accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: Not so; he could make the class implement `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Which would be needlessly complex for what OP is trying to accomplish.

Comment: I agree. It's only where you say he 'would have to' do it your way that I disagree with. I'd do it your way.

Comment: @Magus you are correct, 'would have to' was a bit strong in that case. There are definitely other ways to solve this. Some are more complicated than others.

Answer (score 3):

There are so many options.

The easiest thing to do is just to expose a public property that allows just what you want to have allowed:

```
public static class Factory
{
    private static Item[] items = new Item[]
    {
        // items are created here
    };

    public static IEnumerable<IReadableItem> Items{ get { return items; } }
    // ...
}
```

The above code assumes that the `Item` class implements an `IReadableItem` interface that only has the methods and properties on it that you want to allow people to access. You could also *clone* the items list before returning it each time, if you're worried someone might re-cast the `Items` or try to modify it using reflection.  Because the standard LINQ methods all work off of `IEnumerable<>`s, this would allow someone to effectively produce a LINQ query on your items, without exposing overmuch data.

```
List<string> bestItemNames = Factory.Items.Where(i => i.IsBest)
    .Select(i => i.Name)
    .ToList();
```

If you wanted to get really fancy, you could even implement your own LINQ provider. From a language perspective, LINQ expression syntax just maps to specific method names, so if you had a class that implemented a `.Where()` and a `.Select()` method, then you could implement that pretty much however you wanted, and people wouldn't know any different until they tried doing something that your methods didn't support.

Answer (score 1):

use an expression tree

```
public class OtherClass
{ 
    public Item Get(ItemId id)
    {
         return Factory.Get(i => i.id == id);
    }
}
```

and change the get method to

```
 public Item Get(Expression<Func<Item,bool>> filter)
 {
      return items.SingleOrDefault(filter);
 }
```

however, this approach makes little sense unless you are encapsulating some other logic in your factory class i.e. select only rows that are not soft deleted.

Comment: There is not need for expression trees here, delegates will suffice (and I think your code wouldn't actually compile).

Comment: You're absolutely right. I thought arrays implemented IQueryable<T>. A Predicate<Item> would be better suited here, however, Expression trees are composable which allows for optimization when communicating with other linq providers.